# Faster way to parse through a data frame in R to find frequency of values?

Tags: r, data-science

I have a dataframe in R that includes a column for distance (12th column) and whether or not there is a match at that distance (13th column). 1 represents a match, 0 represents no match.
For example:

```
distance    match
1           0
1           1
1           1
2           1
2           0
3           1
4           0
4           0
```

I want to find the frequency of each of the distance values and find the percentage of matches at each of those values.

For example, for the table above, I want to get something like this:

```
distance    frequency    matches
1           3            2
2           2            1
3           1            1
4           2            0
```

The current code I have looks like this:

```
  #Create a new list with unique distance values
  distance <- unique(methyl_data[,12])

  #Count how many of each distance and how many matches there are
  total = c()
  matches = c()

  dl = length(distance)
  ml = length(methyl_data[,12])

  match = FALSE
  tcounter = 0
  mcounter = 0
  for (d in 1:dl) {
    for (x in 1:ml){
      if (distance[d] == methyl_data[x, 12]) {
        match = TRUE
        tcounter <- tcounter + 1
        if (methyl_data[x, 13] == 1) {
          mcounter <- mcounter + 1
        }
      }

      #Add the frequency and number of matches for the last data entry
      if(d== dl && x ==ml) {
        total = c(total, tcounter)
        matches = c(matches, mcounter)
      }
      if((distance[d] != methyl_data[x, 12]) && match == TRUE) {
        match = FALSE
        total = c(total, tcounter)
        matches = c(matches, mcounter)
        tcounter =0
        mcounter =0
      }

    }



  }

  View(distance)
  #Create a table with the frequency of distances and matches and percentage of matches
  percentage = (matches/total)
  table = cbind(distance, total, matches, percentage)
```

However, this dataframe has almost 2 million rows, so this loop is inefficent. Is there any built-in R function that can simplify my code? My ultimate goal is to see if there is a relationship between distance and matches, so is there a simpler way to do that for a very large dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Several nice methods below. It would be interesting to see some benchmarks.  Maybe you can do some benchmarks on (subsets of) your data?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

**Method 1:** Using `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(distance) %>% 
    mutate(frequency = n(), matches = sum(match)) %>% 
    select(distance, frequency, matches) %>% 
    distinct()

print(df)

  distance frequency matches
     <int>     <int>   <int>
1        1         3       2
2        2         2       1
3        3         1       1
4        4         2       0
```

**Method 2:** Using `data.table` package (prefer this if your data is huge)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,':='(frequency = .N, matches = sum(match)), .(distance)]
df <- unique(df[,.(distance, frequency, matches)])

print(df)
       distance frequency matches
1:        1         3       2
2:        2         2       1
3:        3         1       1
4:        4         2       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider your data.frame is `df`. Here you have some alternatives to choose from.

With R base:

**Alternative 1** with two `tapply`s

```
data.frame(distance=unique(df$distance),
             frequency=with(df, tapply(match, distance, length)),
             matches=with(df, tapply(match, distance, sum)))
```

**Alernative 2** with one `tapply`

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(df$match, df$distance, 
                             function(x){
                               c(match=length(x), frequency=sum(x))} ))
cbind(distance=unique(df$distance), out)
```

**Alternative 3** Using `xtabs` and `table`

```
x <- xtabs(match ~ distance, data=df)
out <- cbind(as.data.frame.table(x),
         frequency=as.data.frame.table(table(df$distance))[,2])
names(out)[2] <- "matches"
```

**Alternative 4** Using `aggregate`

```
tmp <- do.call(data.frame, 
               aggregate(.~distance, FUN=function(x){
                 c(match=length(x), 
                   frequency=sum(x))
                 }, data=df ))
names(tmp)[-1] <- c("frequency", "matches")
```

**Alternative 5** Using `rle` and `tapply`

```
x <- rle(df$distance)
data.frame(distance=x$values,
           frequency=x$lengths,
           matches=tapply(df$match, df$distance, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is good case for using the `dplyr` package:

```
> dplyr::group_by(df, distance) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(frequency = n(), matches = sum(match))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  distance frequency matches
     <int>     <int>   <int>
1        1         3       2
2        2         2       1
3        3         1       1
4        4         2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(distance = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4),match=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0))
df<- split(df,df$distance)
distance  <- names(df)
frequency <- unlist(lapply(df,function(i) length(i$match)))
matches   <- unlist(lapply(df,function(i) sum(i$match)))

res <- data.frame(distance, frequency, matches)
```

Note :

Comment: you can replace `unlist(lapply(...))` by using `sapply(...)`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't elegant, but how about this (assuming your dataframe is `df`):

```
num_matches <- c()

for(i in unique(df$distance)){
   num_matches[i] <- sum(df$match[df$distance == i])
}

new_df <- data.frame("distance" = unique(df$distance),
                     "frequency" = as.vector(table(df$distance)), 
                     "matches" = num_matches)
```

Comment: anything that depends on explicit looping is probably going to be slow ...

Comment: I found `for` loops to actually outcompete `apply` in terms of speed. Would love feedback if there's something I'm missing in this code: https://github.com/mmgrobis/For-loops_v_apply

Comment: `for` loops are usually comparable to `apply`.  Vectorized approaches (including `data.table` and tidyverse solutions) are usually much faster.